# jqGrid warning alert resize

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid table. When I try to edit some row without selecting any row, it alerts a warning message, saying "Please, select a row". This pop-up window is resizable and user can resize it, so that it completely disappears. I want this pop-up window not to be resizable. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I found some solution. Don't know if this is the best one, but anyway... In my stylesheet I added:

```
#alertmod .jqResize { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the resizable dialog is hardcoded to `true` in [grid.formedit.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.formedit.js):

```
$.jgrid.createModal(alertIDs,
    "<div>"+o.alerttext+
    "</div><span tabindex='0'><span tabindex='-1' id='jqg_alrt'></span></span>",
    {gbox:"#gbox_"+$t.p.id,
     jqModal:true,
     drag:true,
     resize:true,
     caption:o.alertcap,
     top:o.alerttop,
     left:o.alertleft,
     width:o.alertwidth,
     height: o.alertheight,
     closeOnEscape:o.closeOnEscape, 
     zIndex: o.alertzIndex},"","",true);
```

So judging by this code your solution is a suitable work-around.

I wonder if `resize` is ever necessary for this modal dialog, though. I am inclined to say it should be changed to `false` although more testing would be required to see if there are use cases where it actually makes sense.